# How can I stop my Javascript code once an event handler has been clicked?

Tags: javascript

So my hmtl eventhandeling button is

```
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop()">
```

and the javascript function `stop()` is:

```
function stop()
{
    stop.called = true;
}
```

and I call this function here:

```
....
var interval = setInterval(function () 
{
    // call generation again for each generation, passing in the previous generations best offspring
    best_offspring = generation(best_offspring, characters, amount_offspring, mutation_rate, target_text);
    document.getElementById("output_text").value = best_offspring;
    document.getElementById("generations").value = generations;
    if (score_met) 
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, delay);

if (stop.called)
{
    return;
}

// so that we know that the program has been run atleast once
start = true;
}
```

Do you need more of the code?

Anyway, what I want is to stop the execution when the function is called. But my `interval` loop continues even though the `stop()` function is called. I have also tried to put the ´if(stop.called)`inside`var interval` loop. But that didnt work either.

Any ideas? Do I need to provide more info?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (stop.called)
{
    clearInterval(interval);
}

¿?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var interval = setInterval(function () 
{
    // call generation again for each generation, passing in the previous generations best offspring
    best_offspring = generation(best_offspring, characters, amount_offspring, mutation_rate, target_text);
    document.getElementById("output_text").value = best_offspring;
    document.getElementById("generations").value = generations;
    if (score_met || stop.called) 
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, delay);

if (stop.called)
{
    clearInterval(interval);
    return;
}

// so that we know that the program has been run atleast once
start = true;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, didnt work untill I put the `if (stop.called)` inside the `setInterval` function. Why?

Answer (score 0):

SetInterval returns an Id so you can simply call clearInterval(id);. Return break etc. Doesnt work because it is not really a loop like for and while.